# Command-Line only version of Lubuntu

Tags: command-line, lubuntu

So I visited the Lubuntu [download](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/GetLubuntu) page (specifically because it's lightweight), which happens to be hosted in the Ubuntu Help section of it's website. I tried to find a version of Lubuntu similar to Ubuntu Server (no GUI, visible stacks), but I couldn't find any. Any feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only difference between Ubuntu and Lubuntu is that they both use different Desktop Environments and some different packages. Ubuntu uses **Unity** whereas Lubuntu uses **LXDE**.

According to Lubuntu Wiki:

> Both Lubuntu and Ubuntu share Two Major Important Things:
>
> ```
> Same Core System
> Same Repositories
> ```
>
> Lubuntu and Ubuntu belong to the same family and talking about each as
>   totally different two systems is not correct since they have some
>   things in common.
>
> The differences between Lubuntu and Ubuntu are:
>
> ```
> Different DE - Lubuntu uses LXDE while Ubuntu uses Unity as the default DE.
> Different Default Applications
> ```
>
> Other than that, they are the same. The DE is what makes Lubuntu a
>   lightweight OS, and of course the selected applications too because we
>   make sure to use the lightest applications which are not resource
>   hungry.

**So, essentially Ubuntu Server with no GUI would be the same as Lubuntu Server with no GUI.** Hence, you can go on downloading Ubuntu Server and install LXDE later, if you want a Lubuntu like GUI.